# keep and remove PK indexes to improve query performance, and why?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, primary-key

I am trying to optimize a few stored procedures in a MySQL database. A few columns have more than one index. These columns are used in joins and WHERE clauses.

Which do I keep and which do I remove to improve query performance, and why?

```
select  table_name,index_name,seq_in_index,column_name,non_unique,index_type,comment from  information_schema.statistics
where table_name in('suspicious_activity_report','customer_comment_table','employement_status','Country_Master','Country_Master') 
order by table_name,column_name
```

[image]

Comment: 'Can any one please explain which one to keep'..There is not enough info, you need to examine the explain plans for each of your queries

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: We need to see the queries that you are using, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query's output shows tables from all the databases on your system.  You need to show which database each table is in, like this:

```sql
select table_schema, table_name, index_name, seq_in_index,
       column_name, non_unique, index_type, comment
  from information_schema.statistics
 where table_name in( 'suspicious_activity_report', 
                      'customer_comment_table',
                      'employement_status',
                      'Country_Master') 
order by table_schema, table_name, seq_in_index;
```

You can also say `WHERE ... table_schema = DATABASE()` if you want to show information from only the current database.

This will remove the apparently duplicated indexes from your output.

Multi-column indexes are often added to tables to handle specific query patterns.  Your output shows only one multicolumn index: `country_master(Country_ID, Client_ID)`. This index is suitable for these patterns, among a few others.

- `WHERE Country_ID = <constant> AND Client_ID = <constant>`
- `WHERE Country_ID = <constant> AND Client_ID BETWEEN <constant> AND <constant>`.

Like @P.Salmon said, before you remove indexes, you need to figure out which query patterns use them. You *could* do this by removing them in production and observing where performance collapses. But that's unwise and will anger your users.